# Как найти позицию объекта в Godot Engine?

Tags: godot

Пишу простую игру на GDScript, но не могу сделать одну вещь. Мне нужно узнать, когда объект окажется на определённой x-координате, и переставить на другую. Что-то по типу:
`if pos.x == 10:`
    `pos.x = -10`
Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. прикрепляем скрипт к объекту.
2. в скрипте добавить:

```
func check_for_position():
    if position.x <= 10:
        position = value #для резкого изменения позиции
        position = position.linear_interpolate(to, strength) #для постепенного изменения. to — до какой позиции, strength — шаг интерполяции, то есть за сколько шагов выполнять. принимает значения от 0 до 1, где 0 — не-изменение, 1 — изменение за один шаг.
```

3. докинуть функцию в какую-нибудь виртуальную, что выполняется по умолчанию, например — process(), physics_process(). желательно в physics process, потому что затрагивает физическое свойство.